# c# access to information inside a static method without a return

Tags: c#, static

I borrowed the following code I found [online](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bfc75b57-df16-48c6-92af-ea0a34f540ae/how-to-get-the-handle-of-a-window-that-i-click?forum=csharplanguage) (the comments aren't even mine).  When I click a button on my form, it waits and detects my next mouse click.  Whatever I click on, it gets that information in the winHandle object inside the HookCallback method:

```
    private static LowLevelMouseProc _proc = HookCallback;
    private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;
    static IntPtr hHook = IntPtr.Zero;

    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 && MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam)
        {
            //  The application runs to here when you click on the window whose handle you  want to get                
            POINT cusorPoint;
            bool ret = GetCursorPos(out cusorPoint);
            // cusorPoint contains your cusor’s position when you click on the window


            // Then use cusorPoint to get the handle of the window you clicked

            IntPtr winHandle = WindowFromPoint(cusorPoint);

            // winHandle is the Hanle you need


            // Now you have get the handle, do what you want here
            // …………………………………………………. 
            Debug.WriteLine("Handle: " + winHandle.ToString());


            // Because the hook may occupy much memory, so remember to uninstall the hook after
            // you finish your work, and that is what the following code does.
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(hHook);
            hHook = IntPtr.Zero;


            // Here I do not use the GetActiveWindow(). Let's call the window you clicked "DesWindow" and explain my reason.
            // I think the hook intercepts the mouse click message before the mouse click message delivered to the DesWindow's 
            // message queue. The application came to this function before the DesWindow became the active window, so the handle 
            // abtained from calling GetActiveWindow() here is not the DesWindow's handle, I did some tests, and What I got is always 
            // the Form's handle, but not the DesWindow's handle. You can do some test too.

            //IntPtr handle = GetActiveWindow();


        }
        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    private const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;

    private enum MouseMessages
    {
        WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201,
        WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202,
        WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200,
        WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A,
        WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204,
        WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct POINT
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
    {
        public POINT pt;
        public uint mouseData;
        public uint flags;
        public uint time;
        public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
        LowLevelMouseProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
        IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool GetCursorPos(out POINT lpPoint);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(POINT Point);

    private void GetProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IntPtr.Zero == hHook){
            using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
            {
                hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, _proc,
                    GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is I need to use the information from that object elsewhere in my code.  But, since it doesn't return that information, I'm not sure how I could get access to it.

I don't think I can return it because it goes instead over to the CallNextHookEx method; I've tried putting it in its own class, but inside the HookCallBack method I don't have access to **this.** or datasets or anything else.

So what can I do to get that information from outside the static method HookCallback?

Comment: Why not set a global variable to empty and then upon getting the information you set the information to the global variable?

Comment: @CoderJoe I'd rather say a static variable rather than a global variable (which is static as well). The scope should be reduced to respect encapsulation. Then accessors should be used to provide external access to this data.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? If you're trying to control a 3rd party app, have you considered trying to use the coded UI libraries?

Comment: @SteveTodd I am, but... the problem is that I don't know what the app will be at run time.  It could be literally anything.  I'm trying to get that information from my user without making it too difficult for them to understand how to give me that information.  Thus the clicking - you click a button, then you click the window that you're trying to have my app control, and voila, now my app knows what window you're wanting.

Comment: @GuillaumeD I'm having a hard time finding examples of what you're talking about.  happen to have any good links?

Comment: are you talking about [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming))?

Comment: I mean more the accessors.  I've tried building some into a class but... while I can access them outside the class, I can't access them from inside the static method, so I'm clearly missing something

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13537443/java-accessing-static-method-properly)